# There's no place like home

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

I recently watched *The Wizard Of Oz* and thought that when Dorothy taps her shoes together three times, it would be easier if she used a program to do it. So let's help her.

### Task

Output slippers being tapped together 3 times.

### Output

Slippers being tapped together. A pair of slippers not being tapped looks like this:

```
  __.....__                   __.....__
 / ,------.\                 /.------, \
(  \        \               /        /  )
\  \      ___\             /___      /  /
 \  \   ,'  __`.         .´__  ',   /  /
  \  `.'  ='  `=\       /=´  '=  '.´  /
   `.  `.        \     /        .´  .´
     `.  `.       \   /       .´  .´
       `.  `-.___.'\ /'.___.-´  .´
         `-._      / \      _.-´
             `----'   '----´
```

And a pair being tapped together looks like this:

```
         __.....__     __.....__
        /.------, \   / ,------.\
       /        /  ) (  \        \
      /___      /  / \  \      ___\
    .´__  ',   /  /   \  \   ,'  __`.
   /=´  '=  '.´  /     \  `.'  ='  `=\
  /        .´  .´       `.  `.        \
 /       .´  .´           `.  `.       \
/'.___.-´  .´               `.  `-.___.'\
\      _.-´                   `-._      /
 '----´                           `----'
```

Basically, output

```
  __.....__                   __.....__
 / ,------.\                 /.------, \
(  \        \               /        /  )
\  \      ___\             /___      /  /
 \  \   ,'  __`.         .´__  ',   /  /
  \  `.'  ='  `=\       /=´  '=  '.´  /
   `.  `.        \     /        .´  .´
     `.  `.       \   /       .´  .´
       `.  `-.___.'\ /'.___.-´  .´
         `-._      / \      _.-´
             `----'   '----´

         __.....__     __.....__
        /.------, \   / ,------.\
       /        /  ) (  \        \
      /___      /  / \  \      ___\
    .´__  ',   /  /   \  \   ,'  __`.
   /=´  '=  '.´  /     \  `.'  ='  `=\
  /        .´  .´       `.  `.        \
 /       .´  .´           `.  `.       \
/'.___.-´  .´               `.  `-.___.'\
\      _.-´                   `-._      /
 '----´                           `----'

  __.....__                   __.....__
 / ,------.\                 /.------, \
(  \        \               /        /  )
\  \      ___\             /___      /  /
 \  \   ,'  __`.         .´__  ',   /  /
  \  `.'  ='  `=\       /=´  '=  '.´  /
   `.  `.        \     /        .´  .´
     `.  `.       \   /       .´  .´
       `.  `-.___.'\ /'.___.-´  .´
         `-._      / \      _.-´
             `----'   '----´

         __.....__     __.....__
        /.------, \   / ,------.\
       /        /  ) (  \        \
      /___      /  / \  \      ___\
    .´__  ',   /  /   \  \   ,'  __`.
   /=´  '=  '.´  /     \  `.'  ='  `=\
  /        .´  .´       `.  `.        \
 /       .´  .´           `.  `.       \
/'.___.-´  .´               `.  `-.___.'\
\      _.-´                   `-._      /
 '----´                           `----'

  __.....__                   __.....__
 / ,------.\                 /.------, \
(  \        \               /        /  )
\  \      ___\             /___      /  /
 \  \   ,'  __`.         .´__  ',   /  /
  \  `.'  ='  `=\       /=´  '=  '.´  /
   `.  `.        \     /        .´  .´
     `.  `.       \   /       .´  .´
       `.  `-.___.'\ /'.___.-´  .´
         `-._      / \      _.-´
             `----'   '----´

         __.....__     __.....__
        /.------, \   / ,------.\
       /        /  ) (  \        \
      /___      /  / \  \      ___\
    .´__  ',   /  /   \  \   ,'  __`.
   /=´  '=  '.´  /     \  `.'  ='  `=\
  /        .´  .´       `.  `.        \
 /       .´  .´           `.  `.       \
/'.___.-´  .´               `.  `-.___.'\
\      _.-´                   `-._      /
 '----´                           `----'
```

For reference, the characters used are

```
_-.,/\()='`´
```

### Rules

- The output can have an optional leading/trailing whitespace
- While not explicitly banned, builtins detract from the competition, so please don't post an answer which is simply a single builtin<sup>*</sup>
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in *characters* wins. Characters is chosen due to the use of a multibyte character.

<sub>* For all you killjoys out there, this rule is intended for comedic effect and shouldn't be taken literally</sub>

Comment: does leading whitespace include extra spaces before each line (as long as they are the same amount everywhere)?

Comment: @dzaima Yes, I'll allow that.

Comment: Are you missing the last `untap` from your output?

Comment: @EngineerToast no, sorry, the structure part was left over from the sandbox.

Comment: `´` makes me sad.

Answer (score 8):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>113</s> <s>110</s> 108 characters

```
░╗╬)λ]cw╚╥Æ⁄║RL↓κΟiRDΨ℮≠3*s4sφ¡┐rκ⁾žχ&ν3.ΦƧ⁴ty¬`OΗΒ%Τz׀PΥω╤8⅟∆KΣ⅜4⅔⅝⁰?Z+pķcE□L6⁵/4γ⁽Κ¹‘▓:±↔Ζ`´ŗ⁴@┼⁴┼≥@┼;┼+3∙
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=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)

Explanation:

```
...‘                       push a compressed string of one slipper (one as the top left one) with a leading newline
    ▓                      convert from a multiline string to an array of lines
     :                     dulplicate a copy for reversing horizontally
      ±↔                   reverse horizontally
        Ζ`´ŗ               replace ` with ´
            ⁴              create a copy of the original slipper for the untapped part
             @┼            append a line of spaces after it horizontally
               ⁴┼          append horizontally a copy of the reversed slipper
                 ≥         move this - the untapped version - to the botton of the stack
                  @┼       append a space after the reversed slipper
                    ;┼     append the original slipper after it
                      +    join the two vertically together
                       3∙  multiply vertically three times
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>165</s> 127 bytes

```
Ｆ´´`«‖ＴＰ⪫⪪”}∧≕Ｉ3⁼wＸ¿↔？⁺⊖？◧χêIr﹪≦⎈X⊞c_⁹jＥτＴＣεh⌊Y﹪ＹＹ}φ⬤»[↷¢|nＸ;ＩζCHE⁷ＲrCsd～¢_⊖⦄⎚§⌈▷φＳ¤Iv}›ＲPx!∧⁵Ｆ]üC”`ι»Ｃ⁴²¦⁰Ｃ²¹¦¹²Ｔ⁴²¦²⁴Ｆ²Ｃ⁰¦²⁴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVBBSsNQED2LZ3DpMgh251IRaUtcFBGFCOrCYD6UmIbSlUYQrFBrgqmLEFNj2i/CdJ/c4V1gjhAnpTADb2Ye896M2eta5kX3rK5Zh5RR1qEZnIB1xjpBPEMcw3mx4UUYPLL@2IbS16x/6A/uA@tXqAX8oAFPUXW/ilsWFzEGIUbeAfyx2YYqTlm/V/31yrdy3sPQPxQS60LCrlx8Tml5BDenye25rN4RmfLb2NuFylmnd5ZxecK/Y5q0RQlhH6NnijD0EOSVy/qLpq0rG85CuPs3W41TNZdjjlfaEOudsqClCENllFIIlUghqKBQMhVXmwmlAponpGt2sunU9T8) [Verbose approximation](https://tio.run/##ZZBBi8IwFITP9lcMuTSFNGrwtnja24KXXY@BtBTFQGxL7ArLsvvX40uiWHDgQeablxCmO7W@G1oXwnHw4Oy/YRV@i8Xn4egO3bT3bX@h5Myrt2Kx@3aTHb3tJ/4x2J5/jc5OnAEwRkYZo3tgCVEnSa3Jc0Br3JVItA9k6E5kTyjKSBsZYSKNJLKlabZ5NaI8s0fxwp/4HtT0QSPLOc80n5ZznCNSyQQYtSJgqYO/4n0Yf/hGCazIJqPWAmtFbu/tOUVqQy4VqiqknVWGIYT6GuqLuwE) (I don't know how to write `´` in Verbose mode). Explanation:

```
Ｆ´´`«
```

Loop twice, once with `´`, once with `` ` ``.

```
‖Ｔ
```

Reflect the canvas, transforming the characters, except for the above two, which is why they are special-cased. Note that this causes the right slipper to end up on the left, which is actually correct for the second row.

```
⪫⪪””`ι»
```

Print the compressed slipper string, but with `` ` ``s replaced with the loop character. (Note that the compressed string includes left padding; this means that the reflected string from the first iteration doesn't touch the second string.)

```
Ｃ⁴²¦⁰
```

The right slipper is in the wrong place on the canvas, so copy it to the correct place. (This also makes an extra copy of the left slipper.)

```
Ｃ²¹¦¹²
```

The second row also needs a copy of the pair of slippers, but this is the same way around as they were originally created. (Actually both pairs get copied, so we now have eight slippers.)

```
Ｔ⁴²¦²⁴
```

Delete all unnecessary extra slippers, leaving two rows of two slippers.

```
Ｆ²Ｃ⁰¦²⁴
```

Make two additional vertical duplicates of the whole thing.

Comment: It doesn't mirror because I don't consider them as opposites, not sure if it would be more useful if they mirrored

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + Common Utilities **(<s>268</s> <s>265</s> 258 Bytes)**

Saved a few bytes thanks to Justin Mariner

Bash **(<s>31</s> 21 Bytes)**

```
gzip -d w;cat w w w
```

Additional File named w **(237 Bytes)** *(Base64 Encoded so I can paste it here)*

```
H4sICIT6rlkAA3cAbZFbDsQgCEX/WQV/ziQWV+BOTOgiu4JZ2YAWhVYSGxpOfNyDyExazPiuOQMsmIe1F5YoTHK2OCDOIEnWVzzhTYBZo5oYbuOkAXwRnNS9qTJ0e9SMOVJKneScFXWWW3bUn+XcFUWaack6krsxav2DH5QP8LaHNcxG7wkMSYUsOSenc8oIHYAy0ExRYxKCl5ByZtZLrG0ZrzZA9eSvohU54RwQUGa7CTgFEX7OIf2XhTsMveQvSeYBO9j3Rpglf2PrHgCR75Y6zgCrwGfJczBuZjgy1c1QH8Af0NuE5gAwAA
```

This might be seen as cheating, and I kind of agree :P.

Comment: Could you do `cat w w w` instead of three `cat`s?

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>575 bytes</s> <s>553</s> 551 characters

```powershell
$a="3__.....__222 __.....__
 / ,1.\2233 /.1, \
(3\23\223 /23/3)
\3\2___\22 /___2/3/
 \3\3 ,'3__0.23 .´__3',3 /3/
3\30.'3='30=\2 /=´3'=3'.´3/
3 0.30.23\33 /23.´3.´
33 0.30.2 \3 /2 .´3.´
2 0.30-.___.'\ /'.___.-´3.´
23 0-._2/ \2_.-´
22 0----'3 '----´

23 __.....__33 __.....__
23/.1, \3 / ,1.\
2 /23/3) (3\23\
2/___2/3/ \3\2___\
33.´__3',3 /3/3 \3\3 ,'3__0.
3 /=´3'=3'.´3/33 \30.'3='30=\
3/23.´3.´2 0.30.23\
 /2 .´3.´233 0.30.2 \
/'.___.-´3.´223 0.30-.___.'\
\2_.-´222 0-._2/
 '----´22223 0----'"
0..3|%{$a=$a-replace$_,('`','------',333,'  ')[$_]}
,$a*3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZJBbsIwEEX3PsUIpRqoHDvMX@cYrAhyIxSJBVIRqOqi7a04ARdLvwOBJFJk@/8Z2@8np8/v7nw5dMdj3xdtvUBKIT8pmZk8F06i@HVozACJYe2lcUs0hqxINESsXMNVSomSRI4WEZ1QhHjlvlVgabhdU4J6NtGlVwVFrajqhl317QqtoazKrlQBuavBcEZW@TqMBjenLqNug1zyuiloI1GHWTm67KJnUXjLrDresyr5KETzSClXPaExmdO4Y@ORBE@7Y8s9B2cjs4w58KIzXMzCIN6cF9l/xeHwQrZnEm4CbJMg3Jw2f5VpGO7BbANzTsGNzJSGaHIQC1eFgN@3H/4KRVueu9Ox3XdF8kv9UD80sMoD8Cqiq22Rdn/OF@07@r5fbveH9rzd7XTztdFVj38)

Simple repeated character replacement. *Edit - saved two characters by using `$a` and looping the `replace` commands.*

Comment: Remember, it's scored by characters, not bytes.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Ah, thanks. I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>495</s> 468 bytes

```python
r,R,s,a,b=str.replace,range(12),str.split,"/(`","\\)\xb4";A=B=r(r("  __.....__8 @ / ,------.#8@(  #8#       @#  #      ___#      @ #  #   ,'  __`.    @  #  `.'  ='  `=#   @   `.  `.8#  @     `.  `.       # @       `.  `-.___.'#@8 `-._      /@"+" "*13+"`----' @","#","\\"),"8"," "*8)
for _ in(0,1,2):B=r(r(r(B,a[_],"*"),b[_],a[_]),"*",b[_])
A,B,j=s(A,"@"),[_[::-1]for _ in s(B,"@")],"\n".join
for _ in"*"*3:print j(j(" ".join((A[_],B[_])[::p])for _ in R)for p in(1,-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDBboMwDIbvewrLHJq0Jh3tDogJKfAIvZYq0KnbQBVFgcP29MwmrJaQfn92ftsMv9P3oz/Ms6cTjdTQNR8nb/xtuDcfN/JN/3VTyUGT0HG4txPhXtVIWFW6@rm@4XuRl7lXXiGAc0bCuRQs7IHiJUyUWgUQpRGEsCxW7ZxblYWV0kZwbQIUVBtGOX91HgUIUq6NONrldchX/2iFK455IWc2kU0XHSp7izsE3CbHHday5QYsXxUtl6EmTFlxPdUvnw8PDtpevVJCB52Fc70qqTm7C@GW26@iJNWSL6l@KaikLh9VQWi55@zOWRYnl38/GNlCKuxR9Wi6R9s/h7HL9pgNvu0n6FTHfzc0KFXIqFIGsN1w0U@70yIH2TShONF6nv8A)

Excited to read Mathematica 12's update notes. (`SlippersTapped@3` only requires 16 bytes!)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 140 bytes

```
"_ ./,-\)'´="•3₅Cæ¶ÿâsΣkÞ₂ÏÕ›|Y=ß°«:ws^N5%ÖΩjĆR["DĀó©›tØ¹oÜ™¾týǝàZ½aÕL.sΔÊÑû8&+››₄|wεŠ8ε¼áNsHÑŽJнi'`³Ö!èÆžIIƵò•11вèJ20ô∞¶¡ε2ä`"´"'`:‚}6FíD»,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AeYAGf8wNWFiMWX//yJfIC4vLC1cKSfCtD0i4oCiM@KChUPDpsK2w7/DonPOo2vDnuKCgsOPw5XigLp8WT3Dn8Kwwqs6d3NeTjUlw5bOqWrEhlJbIkTEgMOzwqnigLp0w5jCuW/DnOKEosK@dMO9x53DoFrCvWHDlUwuc86Uw4rDkcO7OCYr4oC64oC64oKEfHfOtcWgOM61wrzDoU5zSMORxb1K0L1pJ2DCs8OWIcOow4bFvklJxrXDsuKAojEx0LLDqEoyMMO04oiewrbCoc61MsOkYCLCtCInYDrigJp9NkbDrUTCuyz//w)

**Explanation**

```
"_ ./,-\)'´="                                   # push this string
             •...•                              # push a base-255 compressed number
                  11в                           # convert to a list of base-11 numbers
                     èJ                         # index into the string with these and join
                       20ô                      # split in pieces of size 20
                          ∞                     # mirror, giving us a pair of shoes 
                                                # both using the char "´"
                           ¶¡                   # split on newlines
                             ε                  # apply to each row
                              2ä`               # split in 2 pieces on stack
                                 "´"'`:         # replace "´" with "`" in the 2nd string
                                       ‚        # pair them up
                                        }       # end apply
                                         6F     # 6 times do
                                           í    # reverse each
                                            D», # print a copy joined on space and newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>328</s> <s>326</s> 316 bytes

```python
s=[''.join(' '*int(c)if'/'<c<':'else c for c in l)for l in r"2__.....__9 1/1,------.\8 (2\8\7 \2\6___\6 1\2\3,'2__`.4 2\2`.'2='2`=\3 3`.2`.8\2 5`.2`.7\1 7`.2`-.___.'\ 9`-._6/ 94`----'1 0".split()]
r=[''.join(dict(zip("`/\\(","\xb4\\/)")).get(c,c)for c in l[::-1])for l in s]
for a,b in(zip(s,r)+zip(r,s))*3:print a,b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBNboQwDIX3cwqLjZNpCCVQ/jScZIySDmXaVAhQYNH28jRhgxfW9yT7Wc/L7/Y1T2rf1/aOKL9nOzEEvNppYz23T0zw1t@wwWFcB@jhOTvf7QQjDzgGdJHSWobSuoY0SUV8lKQKmKKKSiBFhdaaCkg9ZgL9hpE5KFJGompRmZYyyIz0uiIFbweVlEIZKPbWWiJBHbBIoM5NOIEpvEZyXUa7Md5d3Bniw/Yb@7MLi0xCxCIR0c8jJ0p4xLn8HHw80fMzzr1p4rQ7Q63dJfC7eHh1GK3C8ZcATqycX7Nmcf5LYWLf/wE)

Comment: [327 bytes](https://tio.run/##RZDBboMwDIbvfQqLi5MuBCVlZaDyJDUKK6VbJgSIcNj28szhsPrw6/uT2Naf@Wf9nEa7baG@IuqvyY8CAY9@XEUn/QMzvHQXrLAfQg8dPKaF1Y8wyIgDY2Kd07GcK8FkRqV7aaI3EJaVqAAiprNzjhXM7k4KubPVObCxrUZbo21rvoBTq/mAGy287lgQGSgiprzGaSSCMvI5gzJv4z40YBId5sGvQjaH5Znn7rtV/PpZJG1GJBKV0PctJ8pkIqX@6Dmp6uQz2bWqUtP854PQHCK/qxu7fVBQi3yJsKgg5fFUzQt/WHyxbX8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 219 bytes

```
00000000: ec93 d1c9 8630 0c00 df33 c5bd e5ff 419b  .....0...3....A.
00000010: 09dc a410 8774 0227 fb34 a0d4 9011 7aa0  .....t.'.4....z.
00000020: 147a 88e4 08b8 b71b 7732 c39d 602c 6bd0  .z......w2..`,k.
00000030: 3a19 6b6b b0d0 e50f 5e21 9b36 1cfe a5bf  :.kk....^!.6....
00000040: 82bb 7f55 73f7 d734 2154 5814 dcf7 c643  ...Us..4!TX....C
00000050: 3b0f 77d0 e531 c3db 9bc2 a6b0 6f1d 02db  ;.w..1......o...
00000060: ce03 7403 6de7 11e6 ed11 cff8 b336 7c3a  ..t.m........6|:
00000070: 5e02 490d d30a ed15 d7e6 ee4d 3ba6 715a  ^.I........M;.qZ
00000080: 9344 2804 4627 082d 8cc1 ba50 40ef c375  .D(.F'.-...P@..u
00000090: 2b90 cba4 4e45 1218 e349 d582 4f35 a922  +...NE...I..O5."
000000a0: f0cd 25d5 f821 9792 6af6 00b9 9314 a327  ..%..!..j......'
000000b0: c899 042b bda2 93a4 f933 905b c990 2189  ...+.....3.[..!.
000000c0: b998 3c3d c8e4 7422 30f7 6bee d7dc afb9  ..<=..t"0.k.....
000000d0: 5f73 bfe6 7efd 36e4 f217 00              _s..~.6....
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZNbaxcxEMXf/RSnBalQDZN70iooXsAHLw8KolDNVbAWEVsKRfzq9eTfLTqwuyFkfjkzZ7Ze1Pp9fL04u76WLY4wWrboumWkYAXSRNCntWi@dgw/J5zOFVArhI9diyfqzg1BkyG5NxSnBSlGBzEmYlbrUKQ7ZNEasRTZGOfqQLm1uLplGDK0iwUpDaanmlCjrojRGjSbO4KYhlD7YlztKOrSKPXl/uktw5Jhi848FSqq8OjwMuGH0cjVBug2B4qvEzhSp6eLcbKnwvpuDEdGMpUXT@8R7YzokWUY7R180g69ca8FZ3e1vP@llNt792Ehnm4Mv3RUXhzjToLVrKBXSmgGJVRBmLqzR9zDsbpUSt/U8@OfjkBGG2IRHV@hjwitR8Do7GSbk@2xLCg2W5aOc3Wmtgi/jzZGJMMPMXBZOrqVstI9C1qg4TpVFjK0J@NEvbwlvDpWPz9ujERGto4NSOLgAm2VZDpSaxq1eIGTMVlf9NTx7J56caAekPH2sVIXGyOTYWoWtFrIGM5DG50wrMvoPlHgtB4lGwMcMvn1c74o541X@xujkDGldRjfPWZajsZsEMoMEKmZKmlOsRTIftxVak@pbzf1HGyMunqacoY4w/noxTCJimbmrGfxFS1TJaXlnbeHu2yrPi3Yxmhk1JwTLC0ljcMaHXVb4VSEOga7u/6EWXeMh4/ozb6o3ajdMvryZUaLOmlEHJNGBIKm0ewu5/v/@MwB@3MzotfXfwE)

Format: **DEFLATE**
Maximum attempted iterations: **10000**
Decompressing iterations: **1019**

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 455 bytes

```
for(_="  Y#YXY WWWV#VU---T.TT, S ,TT.R__QW/PQ_O/OWPY/N%.Y%MM-.O.'L%-._WPK.´JJYJI#0H-´G/'.O.GYJFJQY',PY/EV DX#W,'YQ%.C/=´Y'=Y'JY/BX%.'Y='Y%=#AD @Q.....Q?@ >Y?>> ?0 /R#>@/SH(Y#@#>WP@/Y)0XUO#>W N0 C>E0YADB0WM.@XP@I0WYM.D#PDI0DL# F0>K U_.G0>W %T-'W'TG0>?WY?0@/S#PRHD/@/Y) (Y#@HVN XUOHW EWC0WBWYA0Y/@IDM.@H /DI>YM.DHF>VLHU_.G>> K0 'TG>>>%T-'0";G=/[>-Y]/.exec(_);)with(_.split(G))_=join(shift());f=a=>_.replace(/./g,a=>`\\\`
`['#%0'.indexOf(a)]||a).repeat(3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc7dbqpAEADg@z7FphuySwK7m/TSsKCiAv4AFlkmtUFioaUxYtT09KKP5RP4Yp5lribz8818Vz/VZX9uT1f72H3Uj0fTnWnpPCMEGApASqkc5xvbtjOWZRZ6RVaWsXVZpoonaRnzWCXAVwYDY7m0WczIwrBZqZI5u9@iCKIQi8C@32ac6OYMommUArH0ziRHfoGVRSA12Jg79xsQB0gEfFQYjIBDwHDw0EdeyvpIXQ9JcKVErkB8jaXHXwMK2MNSJR4HUxSbWOdoJdBYTgQM/ZFQS@YViRcKBUvm48QPhb/AaCrkHG1KNhN63shsokimc1eBKzSLk3Xg895E/YEgXyFtBwpN1FiokYKhAO6FvsYDxP1Q9ngwlfki6FH94lwgLUope1w8D2YOf5M2vHNW/9Z7WpoD8197/aIlu5wO7ZXOTLN0vrv2SC9fbXOlpjlonMqRJTvXp0O1ryln/NPSld12u9097d4INgRh7fGj/o0bWpnvf3@V2U/X1ZW@mI99d7x0h5oduk/aaO/xHw)